# Add days to a date time format

Tags: php

How can i extend a date by days using php.
I am using the following code to set joining time for a particular subscription. now i have to add expiry interval which is in days to make for expiryDate and to store it in database. eg:
'2014-02-21 07:28:13' + 2 days = '2014-02-23 07:28:13'.

```
$newSubscription->setJoiningtime(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::modify()`](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.modify.php). Like this:

```
$date = new \DateTime('2014-02-21 07:28:13');
$newSubscription->setJoiningtime($date->modify('+2 days'));
```

The `date()` function is not required here.